# Basemap plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot data onto a Python Basemap. The code I am using is...

```
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from numpy import meshgrid

    plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(18, 9), dpi=80, facecolor='w', 
    edgecolor='k')
    xx, yy = meshgrid(lon, lat)
    map = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0=-90, lon_0=0,
          resolution='l')

    map.pcolormesh(xx,yy,wind_ts_final_freeze[:,:], 
    cmap='terrain_r',vmin=0, vmax=38, latlon=True)
    map.drawcoastlines()

    map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 30),labels=[0,0,1,1])
    map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 30))

    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Temperature (aboove 273.15 K)', fontsize=16)

    plt.show()
```

The "data" in shape (361,576) and values range from 0 to 38. When I plot the data is shows all vales as 38 even though most at 0.

I imagine it has something to do with how the data is gridded but I am having trouble overcoming this hurdle. Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you show me the shape of XX and YY?

Comment: Yes, The shape of XX and YY are (361, 576)

Comment: Try adding in `x, y = m(xx, yy)` after you declare your `map` object, and then change `map.pcolormesh(xx,yy...)` to `map.pcolormesh(x, y,...)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked!